# How to put an alias for a url?

Tags: urls

I have an url and put this to my slice (beamer) using

```
...
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask}
...
```

in my view i see this "https://www.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask" and i wondering how i can replace this url for an alias and keep the link to a page; for example "ask"

Comment: Load the `hyperref` package and use `\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask}{Alias}`.

Comment: @hooy Could put your comment as an answer?  I went to say the same thing and caught myself when I saw your comment, which answers fully.

Comment: @hooy small addition: loading `hyperref` is not necessary, it is already loaded by `beamer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `beamer` loads `hyperref` automatically you can just issue `\href{link}{alias}`.